# PSQL generar datos aleatorios procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, postgresql

Necesito crear un procedimiento almacenado sin generate_series en el que se inserten a lo mejor 100.000 registros en una tabla sencilla de forma aleatoria dejo una tabla de ejemplo para que me digáis como lo haríais

`create table prueba( id serial primary key, nombre varchar(20), numero int, nacimiento datetime );`

para esa tabla como generaríais de forma aleatorio 100.000 registros en un procedimiento ?? llevo dos horas buscando formas y nada

Answer (score 0):

Si los datos no necesitas que sean coherentes seria recorrer un bucle 100000 y hacer insert

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bucle100(
        )
        RETURNS void
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100
        VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    AS $BODY$
    
    BEGIN
    
    FOR i IN 1..100000 LOOP
     
          insert into "prueba" ("id","nombre","numero","nacimiento") values(i,'name x',i,'2022-02-16'); 
            
    END LOOP;
    END;

$BODY$;
```